# Task doesn't update local variable

Tags: javafx, concurrency

I'm using a Task to read a text file, the task is invoked when the user clicks "open file" menu, it is supposed to read the text file, and then update the local variable "text", the problem occurs at the first try, if i open a file, nothing happens, and the value of the text string stays as it is, if i open any file **again**, everything works as expected, i couldn't find the cause of this.

The method that has the task

```
private void readFile(File file){
    Task<String> task = new Task<String>() {
        @Override
        protected String call()  {
            List<String> list = EditorUtils.readFromFile(file);
            String str = list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
            return str;
        }
    };

    task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
            setCurrentText(task.getValue());
        }
    });
    task.setOnFailed(e -> setCurrentText("FAILED"));
    Thread t = new Thread(task);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
}
```

SetCurrentText

```
private void setCurrentText(String text){
    this.text = text;
}
```

The method of the controller

```
@FXML
void openMenuItemClick(ActionEvent event) {
    fileChooser.setTitle("title");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add
            (new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("TXT files (*.txt)", "*.txt"));
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(open.getParentPopup().getScene().getWindow());
    if (file != null){
        readFile(file);
        System.out.println(text); //prints null since "text" isn't initialized yet
    }
}
```

EditorUtils#readFromFile

```
public static List<String> readFromFile(File file){
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file.getPath()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lines;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `readFile` method creates a `Task`, gives it to a `Thread`, launches the `Thread`, and returns. You then try to immediately print out the value of `text`. There's no guarantee your `Task` will have completed by the time you call `println(text)`. In fact, it's very likely your `Task` has not completed yet. But that's not the only problem.

The call to `readFile` and `println` are both done on the same thread—in this case, the *JavaFX Application Thread*. The problem here is that the `EventHandler` you pass to `setOnSucceeded` will be invoked on the FX thread as well. The way this is achieved internally is with a `Platform.runLater` call which schedules the action with the FX thread to be ran *some time in the future*. This can't happen while the FX thread is executing `openMenuItemClick` and must wait until the method returns.

What this all means is that `setCurrentText` *will never run until after the call to `println`*. But by the second time `openMenuItemClick` is invoked the `text` will have been set<sup>1</sup>. So what you're seeing the second time is actually the result of the first `Task`.

If you want to do something with `text` once the `Task` completes then you should do it inside the `onSucceeded` or `onFailed` handler. Or you can make `text` a `StringProperty` and observe  it for changes.

---

<sup>1. Technically, it **may have** been set. There's still no guarantee the `Task` has completed by then.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly normal behaviour when using multiple threads. You access the file from a task running on background thread. On completion this task triggers an update on the JavaFX application thread.

By the time `readFile` returns the task may not have been completed. The fact that `Task` uses `Platform.runLater` to execute the `onSucceeded` handler results in this handler never being invoked before the `openMenuItemClick` method completes, even if the file is read before `System.out.println` is reached.

If you need to update the GUI based on the result of the `Task`, you should do so from the event handler. The code updating the `text` field runs after the `System.out.println(text);` statement. The second time you start the task, you print results of the task started the first time the menu item was clicked, not the new one. You can verify this by moving the `println` to the beginning of the `openMenuItemClick` method.